Pandas vectorized function to find time to grow n% from starting cell
I have a pandas DataFrame with a time series (in this case price of a used car model) and am looking for a vectorized function to map each cell to the time it takes the price to grow n percent from that cell (if it never reaches n% more then return nan)
It should in theory be possible to execute in a vectorized way as the output of each row is independent of what comes before it
Here is a sample of the data and expected output
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime


df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        1490.47,
        1492.98,
        1494.69,
        1497.43,
        1499.02,
        1503.29,
        1501.60,
        1502.80,
        1502.30,
        1509.38,
        1512.01,
        1508.98,
        1512.63,
    ],
    columns=['price'],
)

df.index.names = ['time']

n=1/100


So in this case I want to run for n=1/100 so compute for each cell the time it takes the price to increase by 1%. So for the first cell, 1% grows would be at 1490.47*1.01 = 1505.3747, the first cell greater than this value is 1509.38 which is 9 cells after the first cell so the output for that cell would be 9, and so on for the rest...
Expected output would then be:
df.some_functions(n=1/100)

print(df)

        price
time         
0     9
1     8
2     8
3     nan
4     nan
5     nan
6     nan
7     nan
8     nan
9     nan
10    nan
11    nan
12    nan

The latter 10 being nan because the price does not grow to greater than 1% of their cell in the remaining DataFrame.

Another option is to use numba (you can even easily parallelize the task):
import numba


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def search(price, n, out):
    for idx in numba.prange(len(price)):
        p = price[idx]
        search_for = p * n
        for idx2, v in enumerate(price[idx:]):
            if v >= search_for:
                out[idx] = idx2
                break


df["out"] = np.nan
search(df["price"].values, 1.01, df["out"].values)

print(df)

Prints:
        price  out
time              
0     1490.47  9.0
1     1492.98  8.0
2     1494.69  8.0
3     1497.43  9.0
4     1499.02  NaN
5     1503.29  NaN
6     1501.60  NaN
7     1502.80  NaN
8     1502.30  NaN
9     1509.38  NaN
10    1512.01  NaN
11    1508.98  NaN
12    1512.63  NaN


On my AMD 5700x it took ~0.8seconds to compute dataframe with 1_000_000 np.random.uniform(1000, 2000, 1_000_000) values.

Code
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = df['price'].values > df['price'].mul(1.01).values[:, None]

df['result'] = np.where(
    np.any(arr, axis=1), 
    np.argmax(arr, axis=1) - df.index, 
    np.nan
)

df
    price   result
0   1490.47 9.0
1   1492.98 8.0
2   1494.69 8.0
3   1497.43 9.0
4   1499.02 NaN
5   1503.29 NaN
6   1501.60 NaN
7   1502.80 NaN
8   1502.30 NaN
9   1509.38 NaN
10  1512.01 NaN
11  1508.98 NaN
12  1512.63 NaN

This method uses vectorized operations, which are faster than loop. However, it generates square 2D array(equal to the length of df), so if df is too large, memory issues can arise. Be cautious of this when using the approach.

Update answer
If you only need to find rows after the current row and your data is not sorted by value, use the result of applying the np.triu function to np.where.
df['result'] = np.where(
    np.any(np.triu(arr), axis=1), 
    np.argmax(arr, axis=1) - df.index, 
    np.nan
)


A nice and simple solution for smaller DataFrames. However, I found this returns negative numbers when the price was at a higher point before the current cell.

@dg141 I've updated the answer for your case.

An efficient approach both computation and memory-wise would be to perform a conditional_join using janitor:
# !pip install pyjanitor
import janitor

n = 1/100
target = df['price'].mul(1+n)

df['diff'] = (target.reset_index()
       .conditional_join(df['price'].reset_index(),
                         ('price', 'price', '<='), ('time', 'time', '<'),
                         how='left', keep='first')
       .assign(diff=lambda x: x[('right', 'time')]-x[('left', 'time')])
       .set_index(('left', 'time'))['diff']
      )

Output:
        price  diff
time               
0     1490.47   9.0
1     1492.98   8.0
2     1494.69   8.0
3     1497.43   9.0
4     1499.02   NaN
5     1503.29   NaN
6     1501.60   NaN
7     1502.80   NaN
8     1502.30   NaN
9     1509.38   NaN
10    1512.01   NaN
11    1508.98   NaN
12    1512.63   NaN

Intermediate:
(target.reset_index()
       .conditional_join(df['price'].reset_index(),
                         ('price', 'price', '<='), ('time', 'time', '<'),
                         how='left', keep='first')
       .assign(diff=lambda x: x[('right', 'time')]-x[('left', 'time')])
      )

   left            right          diff
   time      price  time    price     
0     0  1505.3747   9.0  1509.38  9.0
1     1  1507.9098   9.0  1509.38  8.0
2     2  1509.6369  10.0  1512.01  8.0
3     3  1512.4043  12.0  1512.63  9.0
4     4  1514.0102   NaN      NaN  NaN
5     5  1518.3229   NaN      NaN  NaN
6     6  1516.6160   NaN      NaN  NaN
7     7  1517.8280   NaN      NaN  NaN
8     8  1517.3230   NaN      NaN  NaN
9     9  1524.4738   NaN      NaN  NaN
10   10  1527.1301   NaN      NaN  NaN
11   11  1524.0698   NaN      NaN  NaN
12   12  1527.7563   NaN      NaN  NaN

